# Vue3 project not working after vite build in production mode

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vite

I have a project that works fine when running in `development` mode, but if I build the project using `vite build´, some components does not work.

There is no error on console nor in the build logs.

Using the `vite build --mode development` generate the bundle and the project works good.

[I've created a POC](https://github.com/igormaozao/vue3-vue-collapsible-panel-bug-demo) to make easier to show you guys the problem.

Comment: Do you run `npm run preview` after your build?

Comment: Indeed, I can reproduce the issue. No errors in the console either.

Answer (score 0):

The [vue-collapsible-panel](https://github.com/dafcoe/vue-collapsible-panel) package you're using is not very popular and there is [this open issue](https://github.com/dafcoe/vue-collapsible-panel/issues/26) when making a production build, so I guess it's unrelated to Vue/Vite.

I recommend that you maybe use some other package with more popularity/support.
You may find something interesting here: https://github.com/vuejs/awesome-vue#menu

Comment: the question's asker is the one that opened the issue u mention (: